# How to call a function defined in "onMounted" lifecycle hook in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```js
<script setup lang="ts">

function callSomething() {
   something(); //not working
}

onMounted(() => {
function something() {
    console.log("Hello, World");
 }
});
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="callSomething">Click</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

In `Vuejs` I want to call a function from `<script setup lang="ts">` which is defined in `onMounted` lifecycle hook. Though, I can call function/method from `onMounted` that defined in `<script setup lang="ts">`

Error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: something is not a function
```

Comment: May I know the use case of calling a method inside `onMounted()` ? As per it's name it called when component mounted. For a button click, you can call a method directly.

Comment: @CreativeLearner In Vue as far as I observed, Vanillajs code is accessible only within `onMounted` lifecycle hook and I had some `vanilajs` code and `events` with some logic. I needed to call a function, and inside that function I had some `events` references. Thats why actually I needed to call method defined in `onMounted`.

Comment: But as per the digest cycle this hook will work on component mount and after that if you want to execute any code based on any event that you have to call directly a method. You can access vanilajs code outside of onMounted() method as well.

Comment: @CreativeLearner for example `let  sliders = document.querySelector(".carouselbox");` without put this statement inside `onMounted`, `sliders` is not executing when it is inside `<script setup lang="ts">` only

Comment: It should work, What issue you are facing ? It's just a normal `querySelector` method.

Comment: ```sliders.insertAdjacentHTML();
``` when `sliders` inside `<script setup lang="ts">` got error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertAdjacentHTML')` but works fine when within `onMounted`

Comment: looks like you forget to write a dot (or a # if they're IDs) before your selectors. that's the reason you are getting that error. Its not related to onMounted()

Comment: its a class and I added dot properly. And, why then same statement works inside `onMounted`?

Comment: why are you unaccepting/accepting the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `something` function is defined only in the scope of the `onMounted` callback, try to define it outside it to be available for the hook and the other function :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

function callSomething() {
   something(); //not working
}

function something() {
    console.log("Hello, World");
 }
onMounted(() => {

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As per it's name `onMounted()`, This life cycle hook always execute when component mounted for the first time. For a button click, you can call a method directly outside of this `onMounted()`.

```
<button @click="callSomething">Click</button>

function callSomething() {
   // Logic can come directly here.
}
```